# Standalone Java Applications

Tags: java, compilation, executable

is there a way to compile java files into executable with high quality free software and without going through using executable JAR files?

Comment: Dupe of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/147181/how-can-i-convert-my-java-program-to-an-exe-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a nice page on [Javalobby](http://www.javalobby.org/articles/java2exe/) that discusses this in some detail, as well as going through several different styles you might want to do this and providing links to appropriate tools (broken down into free and commercial).

Some of the free EXE-generating tools are

1. [jstart32](http://jstart32.sourceforge.net/)
2. [Launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
3. [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)

and while I've never needed one of these so can't offer my opinion on their effectiveness, they all appear to do the simple task well.

Comment: JWrapper is another free option.  Disclaimer: my company makes it.

Answer (score 4):

There are [several ways](http://www.excelsior-usa.com/articles/java-to-exe.html) to do it. But you should in general avoid making a java application executable on one platform just because you don't like double clicking JAR files. That defeats the purpose of interoperable nature of Java.

Comment: Agree. A better approach is to provide a JAR file and a bunch of launchers, i.e. .bat, .sh etc

Comment: Why was this downvoted? I thought it was quite a good point.

Comment: The poster wants to compile Java files into executables. What does that have to do with interoperability? He does with his Java programs what he wants.

Comment: Just because you're providing an EXE to launch your Java program doesn't mean you don't care about interoperability.  And just because you're using Java doesn't mean you DO care about interoperability either.

Comment: @eljenso: In most operating systems nowadays JAR files *are* indeed executable.

Answer (score 2):

There are several wrappers available. I have no experience with them, but you might try the following or google for some more:

- http://www.regexlab.com/en/jar2exe/
- http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

In others words, you want to create an EXE file from your JAR file ?
There are some software for that, such as [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net) or [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)